# Install same application

Tags: android, installation

Hi I have a problem with application

The real problem maybe is not on application, I develop my application in my computer but when I copy the project another computer and I have installed the application of first computer and when install the application by the second computer I can't reinstall it unless that install the by first computer. Have any sign or any feature??

Thanks!!

Comment: This is because they were signed by different keys. Have a look at: (http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copying .android folder to second computer may work. You can try it.

```
 (Users/{username}/.android)
```

Comment: Have any form to use the same sign on two computers or more??

Answer (score 0):

You have different debug keys on each computer => Android checks sign on installing and reject installation. You should remove your application from the device before install from another computer.

Comment: Have any form to use the same sign on two computers or more?

Comment: You could try to copy the debug keystore from one computer to the other, the debug keystore is used to "sign" your debug version.